# Exclude a folder from android's ADB PULL

Tags: android, adb

So I am trying to make a FULL BACKUP of my Galaxy S8's SD CARD (actual removable sd card). So I am using the Android ADB feature to use this; I use the following command to backup my SD CARD;

**"adb pull /storage/5C60-4517/"** --> This works totally fine, however I have one issue.

In my SD CARD I have a folder called "**PCMusic"** which is where all my music is stored. It's the same music I have on my PC and network HDDs, so what I want to do is **EXCLUDE this ONLY folder as I already have all this music on my PC HDD.** This folder is around 17GB so it wastes more than enough time while backing up my SD CARD. This folder is located on the root  drive of the SD CARD.

So I'd like to know using the commands, how can I EXCLUDE this ONE folder from the root of the sd card? I'd like to backup everything else present in the sd card, except for the music folder called "PCMusic".

Thanks. *(I'm only a newbie! Two months into Android!)*

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with the same issue, but for my internal sd. I don't think adb has a built-in option for that, ***but if you are on linux***; this 'for loop' in combination with a 'find' command (which of course can be modified to individual needs) worked for me on my internal sd:

```
for file_or_dir in "`sudo adb shell find /sdcard/ ! -name "'Music'" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1`"
    do sudo adb pull "${file_or_dir}" /path/to/target/sdcard
done
```

This command uses 'adb shell' to perform a 'find' command on the device itself, which results in a list of all files and dirs in /sdcard NOT matching the name 'Music' (sudo adb shell find /sdcard ! -name 'Music' -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1).

Then it loops through this list of files and dirs and individually pulls them all to /path/to/target/sdcard/.
('sudo' can be omitted if you have proper udev rules in place)

(based on this reddit-comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/hnfo5/adb_wildcard_pull/c1wsmic/)

Comment: this is very ineffective way of doing it. Use `tar` on the device side and redirect its stdout on the PC side to a file. Use `tar` command line parameters to exclude files and folders of your choosing.

Comment: Would you mind sharing an example? Because I don't see how using adb pull on a couple of directories (as one would normally do manually) is very ineffective.

Comment: FYI: this does not handle spaces in folder names

Comment: Thanks, I modified my answer somewhat (using back-ticks&double quotes instead of parentheses) so it should support spaces in find's results.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I stumbled upon this thread but I needed the script to run on Windows so I recreated it:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('adb shell find /sdcard/ ! -name "'Download'" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1') DO (adb pull -p -a "%%F" "\path\to\target\sdcard")
```

"delims=" solves the problem with spaces in the path

%%F works in a batch file, %F from the console

I added to the adb pull -p (to show a progress bar) and -a (to keep the original modified date)

I didn't need sudo (probably because I was in TWRP)

Some folders did crash due to some file name/path being too long. To solve that I copied those using:

```
adb exec-out "tar -ch sdcard/Android | gzip -1" > "\path\to\target\sdcard\sdcard_Android.tar.gz"
```

This option is a lot slower but works.

It's VERY important to use an updated adb version, during abd pull using adb 30 I was getting 75Mbps and using adb 42 (I believe is the newest one at the time of writing) I got around 700Mbps.

Using tar and gzip I got around 50Mbps.